# Geany simple linking

Tags: c++, geany

When I run and build a simple program, it fails.
Here is the error message:

> g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" (in directory: /home/markuz/Desktop)
>   /tmp/ccHV9wPu.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to`Test::display()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Compilation failed.

Here are the files. The compile and build command is the default of geany 1.22

```
//main.cpp
#include "imba.h"
int main(){
Test t;
t.display();
return 0;
}

//imba.h
class Test{
public:
void display();
};

//imba.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "imba.h"

void Test::display(){
std::cout << "oi";
}
```

[image]

Any ideas about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also add the `imba.cpp` file in the compilation step. Although you have included the header in your main file, you have not compiled the source for it and so the linker cannot find the object file for `imba.cpp` - that is what the error is complaining about

Comment: I know that. But before, some months ago, when I use geany in another computer it automatically includes and links all the required files when compiling and building as long as all of it are on one directory. I used it before so I know.

Comment: @markuz That may be the case, but clearly your error message shows that it has only included `main.cpp` in the build step.